# Inline Keyboard в TelegramBots

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegrambots

я делаю телеграмм бота на Java и решил сделать клавиатуру под сообщением. Я  сделал тестовый экземпляр клавиатуры, но по нажатию на неё ничего не происходит, не вызывается onUpdatesReceived. Класс бота наследуется от TelegramLongPollingCommandBot.
Вот код создания клавиатуры:

```
private void sendMessage() {
        InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboardMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
        List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> lst2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        InlineKeyboardButton button = new InlineKeyboardButton();
        button.setText("Test11");
        button.setCallbackData("TestBTN");
        InlineKeyboardButton button2 = new InlineKeyboardButton();
        button2.setText("Test22");
        button2.setCallbackData("TestBTN2");
        InlineKeyboardButton button3 = new InlineKeyboardButton();
        button3.setText("Test33");
        button3.setCallbackData("TestBTN3");
        lst.add(button);
        lst.add(button2);
        lst.add(button3);
        lst2.add(lst);
        inlineKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(lst2);
        SendMessage message = new SendMessageBuilder()
                .setChatId(646596194)
                .setText("Пример")
                .setReplyMarkup(inlineKeyboardMarkup)
                .build();
        try {
            execute(message);
        }
        catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: зачем эта туча переменных? сильно ухудшает читабельность

Comment: по существу - ищите примеры реализации в [репозитории библиотеки](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots) которую используете, вопросы туда же адресуйте. слишком узкая тема чтоб тут вам помогли

Comment: У вас как настроено получение сообщений от бота? Через getUpdates или веб-хуки настроены?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {if(update.hasCallbackQuery()){
        String str = update.getCallbackQuery().getData();}
```

Так нужно обрабатывать ответ от inline кнопок в телеграмм ботах

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]